# What's the meaning of 'Browser support' in EJS?

Tags: javascript

Browser support

Download a browser build from the latest release, and use it in a script tag.

```
<script src="ejs.js"></script>
<script>
var people = ['geddy', 'neil', 'alex'],
html = ejs.render('<%= people.join(", "); %>', {people: people});
```

I want to know what's the meaning of 'Browser support' in EJS? What function the code above implement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use same views on frontend and backend. So when requesting asynchronously new data from a server, you will get for example only a JSON which you can pass to your EJS template. It will build plain HTML from it and then you can display it to the user